# Outlet box in the middle of the wall

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I am in the process of insulating my garage with fiberglass and there is one last part that I am not too sure how to solve - I hope somebody here has a good idea/advice.

Basically speaking the garage wall has a hole in the concrete where a bunch of cables for lights, outlets, EV charger and UTP6 get in. They are already stapled on the wall.

Such hole (see the photo below) is exactly at the center of the 2x4 wall - and therefore I cannot simply put an outlet box on the side and let the wires go through. I would like to find a way to retain access to the hole if one day I need to pass another cable through or any repair is necessary.

I have been to HomeDepot but I have not really been able to find anything that would be helping. The closest thing is [this ceiling box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-4-in-24-5-cu-in-Hard-Shell-PVC-New-Work-Electrical-Ceiling-Box-with-Adjustable-Hanger-Bar-BH525H/100124274#overlay) but it's still far from what I need.

Anybody has any idea?

[image]

Comment: Cut back or leave back the drywall over this region. Cover the missing drywall spot with a painted piece of plywood. They make plastic covers for drywall cutouts for access to water valves, e.g. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Acudor-Products-12-in-x-12-in-Plastic-Wall-or-Ceiling-Access-Panel-PA1212/202925869. That could look nicer.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps an "access panel"? They're commonly used when access to plumbing clean outs, outdoor valve shut-offs, etc. are required inside the walls of finished spaces. You'll have to push the insulation out of the way to pull new wires, but it's far better than cutting and replacing drywall. They come in a wide range of sizes.

Example: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Elmdor-8-in-x-8-in-Metal-Wall-and-Ceiling-Access-Door-DW8X8PC-SDL/204144390